# wine nsf screen resolution

Tags: wine, kubuntu

I play NFS with Wine in Kubuntu.

As usual, NFS changed my screen resolution to low, but after it finished, it didn't restore the screen to normal resolution.

I found some code to restore the resolution, but I have to restart the system.

Is there any other solution without restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I got similar problem with NVidia proprietary driver. If you don't mind playing in windowed mode.

- Running NFS in Virtual Desktop mode of Wine.

Wine Configuration (winecfg) → Graphics  → Check: Emulate a virtual desktop

- You can create new profile to be applied only for NFS.

Wine Configuration (winecfg) → Applications

Kind of such problems with wine you may search in https://appdb.winehq.org/